# Sorting columns with gaps in Excel / Google Sheets

Tags: excel, sorting, google-sheets

I'd like to sort several columns in google sheets, but with gaps where there are no matching values in other columns present.

See my example:

Start:

```
c   a   z
a   k   d
d   x   f
e   b   m
x   e   b
```

Sorted:

```
a   a   
    b   b
c
d       d
e   e   
        f
    k
        m
x   x
        z
```

So, is this possible in google sheets and/or Excel? I would prefer google spreadsheets if possible.

Comment: Which one excel or googlesheets? They are two different things.

Comment: @TimWilkinson I could use both, but I would prefer google spreadsheets. Will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Google Sheets try the formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("r"&ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(myRange))))&"c"&TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(INDIRECT(myRange))))),{"r"&VLOOKUP(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE("_"&"_"&INDIRECT(myRange)),"_"))),{UNIQUE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE("_"&"_"&INDIRECT(myRange)),"_")))),ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT(myRange))))},2,0)&ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE("_c"&COLUMN(INDIRECT(myRange))*ROW(INDIRECT(myRange))^0),"_")),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE("_"&"_"&INDIRECT(myRange)),"_"))},2,1,1,1),ROWS(INDIRECT(myRange))*COLUMNS(INDIRECT(myRange)),1),SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE("_"&"_"&INDIRECT(myRange)),"_")))},2,0)))`

To make it work first make named range called `myRange` and paste there an address of desired range:

[image]

Please see my [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bb-HO0dTv6iqu_lMpxunmLdvYbRUaysPOVuXFlAocq0/edit#gid=0) with the solution.

Comment: Looks good, thank you! I will dive into that formula to see what's exactly going on ;-)